# Haskell: selecting lists from a list when a condition is true

Tags: list, haskell, select

i'm trying to select some lists from a list when a condition is true, something like this:

I've made a data structure -> `data File = File {name :: String, size :: Integer, comment :: String} deriving Show`

And i have already made a library with all the files following this structure:

> files = [["name1",size1,"coment1"],["name2",size2,"coment2"],["name3",size3,"coment3"],...]

Now what i need is a function that selects me all the lists which the sizes are for example >= 500, something like

`list = select ((>=500.size) files)`

So if i had:

`files = [["asd",345,"coment1"],["fgh",678,"coment2"],["hjk",123,"coment3"],...]`

I would get:

`list = [["fgh",678,"coment2"]]`

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Prelude contains the useful

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

which does what you intend your `select` to do.

Answering your comment to Jon Purdy's answer:

```
filter ((>= 500) . size) files
```

Aside:

```
files = [["asd",345,"coment1"],["fgh",678,"coment2"],["hjk",123,"coment3"],...]
```

won't work, lists are homogeneous. It should in the context of the question be

```
files = [File "asd" 345 "coment1", File "fgh" 678 "coment2", ... ]
```

`File` having been defined with record-syntax, you can use it with record syntax or vanilla positional syntax, whatever is better in a given situation. Record syntax would be more typing than the above, but if you used it, `files = [File{ name = "asd", size = 345, comment = "coment1" }, ... ]` would continue to work if you added fields to the type - the added fields would then be instantiated with `undefined`, which may or may not be better than the code not compiling without changes.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, my mistake was that i was calling _size_ when the actual name in the data structure was _filesize_ and i thought i was making some kind of mistake. thanks mate

Answer (score 3):

You want `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`, which is in the Prelude.

[A quick Hoogle query](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a-%3EBool%29-%3E%5ba%5d-%3E%5ba%5d) will help you find things like this in the future.

Comment: I'm indeed trying to work with filter, my doubt is, how to I command to filter only the size?

Comment: @seph: `filter ((>=500) . size) list` should be fine. Partial application of an infix operator (`>=`) is called a *section*, and must be in parentheses. You can compose that with `size` in the usual way.

Comment: yeah mate, i made that mistake too, forgot the parentheses, now its all clear, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With an input file like

```
data File = File {name :: String, size :: Integer, comment :: String}
          deriving Show

files = [File "asd" 345 "coment1",
         File "fgh" 678 "coment2",
         File "hjk" 123 "coment3"]
```

then you can use

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

like this to get what you want:

```
filter ((>= 500) . size) files
```